# Getting other field from telephone number

Tags: powershell

I want to get values from Other field telephone number in AD user properties. But , I am getting `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection`  in CSV file.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(emailaddress -like "*@domaina.com" -and Enabled -eq $true -and sAMAccountName -like "MSS*") -or (emailaddress -like "*@domainb.com" -and Enabled -eq $true -and sAMAccountName -like "MRP*")} -SearchBase "OU=Company,DC=contoso,DC=local" -SearchScope Subtree -Properties * ,otherTelephone | Select-Object givenName, sn, displayname,TelephoneNumber,HomePhone,othertelephone,mobile, ipphone, Fax , physicaldeliveryofficename,title,mail |Export-CSV -Path "C:\list.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: As the attribute otherTelephone is a multi valued string it comes back as an array. So instead of plain `otherTelephone` you can use a calculated property `@{Name = "otherPhone";Expression = {@($_.otherTelephone) -join ','}}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess as this is ADPropertyValueCollection you could try to unwrap it with select custom properties such as

```
| Select-Object ..., @{ Name=”OtherTelephone”; Expression={$_.otherTelephone.exactPropertyYouLookingFor}, ...
```